# Given a confidence interval $[L,U], D = L - U,$ calculate $E(D^2)$.

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I had received this homework assignment and I'm not sure how to tackle it.

Let $n\ge1$, $[L, U]$ a confidence interval with a confidence level of $\alpha - 1$, and $\mu$ of minimal length, $D = L - U$ the length of the confidence interval.

Calculate $E(D^2)$

What I'd tried so far is to expand the expression $E(D^2) = E((L - U) ^ 2) = ... = E(L^2) - 2\cdot E(U\cdot L) + E(U^2)$, however I honestly did not know how to proceed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help guys!
I really appreciate it.

- Chen

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I've noticed that in many of your questions you do not provide sufficient context. This is frowned upon here. I'm surprised you don't have more downvotes.

Comment: Thank you @Shaun, I've never been told that before. Let me correct my post!